# Get flushed entities on Doctrine postFlush event

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Consider next steps in Symfony application:

1. Register listener for Doctrine`s `postFlush` event that dump results of `getScheduledEntityInsertions()` of Unit of Work.
2. Create instance of SomeEntity class.
3. Call Entity Manager`s `persist` and `flush` methods with previously created entity instance
4. `postFlush` listener fired
5. `getScheduledEntityInsertions()` call return nothing

Expected behaviour is that at last step I see a list of inserted entities, but if you look at `executeInserts()` method of UoF, `unset($this->entityInsertions[$oid])` called for each entity so nothig is returned from `getScheduledEntityInsertions()` call.

Iam found declined patch for that case: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/5674 and Ocramius suggestion to use "onFlush" event to collect all needed data and fired custom event: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/GLJEx0p5kL4

But, I dont understand, how it can be done: if I register custom listener for `myCustomEvent` and fire it from `onFlush` with list of not inserted entities - it will be executed before entities actually saved to database (`postFlush` fired) and cant be received from database in this listener.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use one Listener class for `onFlush` and `postFlush` event, and in `onFlush` populate internal property with necessary data, in `postFlush` read data from property. But this solution has limitations: both listener-methods must be defined same class; listener is not thread-safe.